# reporting services show/hide column base on dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a few columns and a reporting services Tablix:

```
ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC
  Val1  |   Val2  |   Val3
```

I'm using dynamic query for select the data:

```
@columnList nvarchar(300)
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(max)
SET @sqlCommand = N'SELECT '+ @columnList +' FROM db.Table'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand
```

I'm passing to procedure the columns that I want select... If all the columns specified, the report work perfectly:

```
SET @sqlCommand = 'ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC'
```

But when I specified less columns for the select that the columns there are in the tablix in reporting services:

```
SET @sqlCommand = 'ColumnA,ColumnB'
```

I get error:

> The dataset 'Dataset1' contains definition for Field 'ColumnC'. 
>   This field is missing    from the returned result set from the data source

I know if I hide ColumnC I'll not have this error but after few days searching by the web I not found a solution. In conclution I have the following question:

How can I hide columns that not are in the sql **SELECT** but are in the the Reporting Services Tablix?

Answer (score 0):

> I would suggest you to do this in SSRS layer rather then doing it in
>   your query. for doing in SSRS its quite simple.
>
> 1) Create a Report Parameter of `Boolean Type` label it something like
>   `Display Column Name`.
>
> 2) In Design View Right Click the column you want to hide or show goto
>   `"Column Visibility Tab"` then Select "Show or Hide based on an
>   expression".   In your Expression `

`= Not Parameters!DisplayParam.Value`

> Now at run time your users can select to display that column or hide
>   it.
>
> If you want the column to be shown or hidden without any input from
>   the end user, you can choose the same path but in "Show or Hide based
>   on an expression" use the condition on which you want to show it or
>   hide it.

Comment: Your answer is reasonable... But I need manage the columnList in sql because the user can generate five report diferent depending the columns that he want see in the report... At this point the already has been configure a lot of option for this report....

Comment: Well this is how I go about doing such operation. also if you dont want user to pass values for showing or hiding column. Hide the parameter and pass value to the paramater on run time in your expression.

Comment: Thanks @M.Ali... I found an alternative that function at less... =Fields!MyField.IsMissing... This the link if can help someone http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2012/03/20/building-reports-with-dynamic-datasets/